# Execute bash script from Symfony

Tags: bash, symfony

I want to create a vhost (apache2) from a symfony app. To do that, I have to execute a script file which contain some root commands. This is my service code

```
public function registerTenantDomain(
        string $from,
        string $to,
        string $subject,
        string $template,
        array $context,
        string $domainName,
        string $enterpriseName
    ): void {
        $pathToHelloWorldScript = __DIR__ . "/../../addImmoTenantScript.sh";
        $pathToHelloWorldScript = "/home/username/Projects/immo/immo-project/addImmoTenantScript.sh";
        $process                = new Process(['sh', $pathToHelloWorldScript, '-p 80 -d ' . $domainName . ' -s ' . $enterpriseName]);

        try {
            $process->mustRun();
            $result = $process->getOutput();
            $this->sendMail->send($from, $to, $subject, $template, $context);
        } catch (ProcessFailedException $exception) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }
    }
```

And here, my script file content

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts p:d:s: flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        p) port=${OPTARG};;
        d) domaineName=${OPTARG};;
        s) organisationName=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done

echo "<VirtualHost *:$port>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/$domaineName
        ServerName $domaineName

        ErrorLog /home/username/www/log-apache/error_$organisationName.log
        CustomLog /home/username/www/log-apache/access_$organisationName.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/$domaineName/>
                Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/$organisationName.conf

echo "server.ip.address     $domaineName" >> /etc/hosts
a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-available/$organisationName.conf
service apache2 reload
ln -s /home/username/Projects/immo/immo-project/public/ /var/www/$domaineName
```

And the sudoers file:

```
Cmnd_Alias ADD_IMMO_TENANT = /home/username/Projects/immo/immo-project/addImmoTenantScript.sh *
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
username ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL, NOPASSWD: ADD_IMMO_TENANT
```

When I call the service, a password is required to reload apache2 service, there is no change inside /etc/hosts file, and the file is doesn't created.

What can I do to achieve this goal ?